# Decryption of .pgp file using private keys using linux commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, encryption

I have a requirement to decrypt file (which encrypted and with extension .pgp) using the private keys. I also have private keys which stored in .txt files.

Is there any way i can decrypt the file (BOEHRINGER_SBX1_D_20201130211007.zip.pgp) using unix commands ?

also please share us steps for encrypting file using public keys .

Note: currently we are decrypting with help of one middleware tool and but we would like to do this from unix scripts /commands.

Regards
Sumesh

Comment: I think you'd like to take a look on gpg command.

Comment: @AlfredoCamposEnríquez , thanks for the inputs , do you have any example and link for me to refer ?